# C++ compile error using initializer list on map<string, string>

Tags: c++, dictionary, initializer

Given this class which takes a map as a constructor parameter

```
struct Map
{
    Map(const map<string, string>& map)
    {
    }
};
```

And this sample code to create it

```
string s;
Map j({ {s, s}});
```

I get:

```
Error   C2675   unary '++': '_Iter' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator   BioAgent    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include\xtree  1259
```

If I change the map to map<string, int> and create it with { { s, 1} } there is no error.

If I write a test function, with the same parameter as the constructor:

```
static void Test(const map<string, string>& map)
{
}
```

And call:

```
Test({ {s, s} });
```

It also works fine.

Why is only the constructor failing to implicitly convert the initializer list to the map?

Comment: There is some kind of (parsing) ambiguity here. The `Map j{ { {s, s} } };` [would work](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a1b7or8zK) on the other hand.

Comment: Is that error message the *only* message you get? Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us, and copy-paste the full and complete build-log.

Comment: @JeJe many thanks, the triple braces sorted it.  I also found the multiple entries in the double braces also work, how wierd

Comment: If you make your constructor `explicit` (which anyway probably you should) it will get rid of the ambiguity.

Comment: @pptaszni if I make the ctor explicit, I get the obvious error that the initializer list cannot be converted to Map

Comment: Nope, [it works](https://godbolt.org/z/enYn77z6K) With normal compilers at least.

Comment: Thank you guys for the compiler explorer link, I've never used that before.  @pptaszni ha yes it does work in gcc, sadly this code is cross compiled so I cant just discard the ms compilers.  Anyways I'm happy with the {{{}}} fix even though I do find it strange it works with map<string, int> and in normal functions

Comment: You could also make your conversion constructor `explicit Map(const map<string, string>& map)` to make `Map j( {{s, s}} );` work (everywhere except in MSVC it seems).